# Subclipse in Mac OS Lion shows "Unable to load default SVN client" error

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, osx-lion

After updating to Mac OSX Lion I find that I m unable to use Subclipse. I keep getting this error:

> Unable to load default SVN client

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

I m using Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Have you tried downloading `SVNKit` from the update site of Subclipse?

Go to *Install New Software* and select the Subclipse update site. Select the JNA and SVNKit library as well as the SVNKit Client Adapter.

After, change the interface from JavaHL to SVNKit in the *Preferences → Team → SVN → SVN Interface*.

Comment: dont forget to install the 'SVNkit Client Adapter' (stated as not required)

Comment: At the moment, only works for subversion <= 1.6, though, as SVNKit does not yet support higher versions.

Comment: I have to remember this.  I run into this problem all the time.

Comment: If the update site for subclipse isn't there then use something like http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x (replace 1.10 with the appropriate major/minor version of subclipse... keep the 'x')

Answer (score 49):

For anyone receiving the error:

```
Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.7.x or later required.
```

Using the latest Eclipse Indigo standard 3.7.1 and the latest Subclipse plugin from CollabNet (Collabnet Desktop 3.1.0 for Eclipse 3.5-3.7) for OS X, the problem is not the version of the Subclipse plugin files, it is the actual version of Subversion you have installed. Collabnet does not yet offer the 1.7 SVN package for OS X, you need to get it from WanDisco.This messed me up for hours.

Comment: Specifically, you want 
 - Vanilla Subversion 1.6.17 & 1.7.0 certified by WANdisco (this worked for me: http://www.wandisco.com/get/?f=subversion-binaries/1.7/Subversion-1.7.2_10.7.x.pkg)
NOT WanDisco's "uberSVN"

Comment: Spot on mate. This worked perfectly...I've been struggling with this for 2 hours now.

Comment: I installed the package you mentioned, but in my console when i type svn --version it shows me 1.6.7. should i change something in my system?. i must to say that i added in /etc/paths this line /opt/subversion/bin according to the installation notes.

Comment: Ok, it was fixed by adding export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH in ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

if you have subclipse version 1.8.x installed, you can also downgrade to 1.6.x
that solved the problem for me 
here's the repository: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

just make sure to remove everything that's related to the higher versions of subclipse (client adapter, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when I tried to re-install subclipse after installing Lion. The subversion client that subclipse uses relies on a javahl bridge which you can normally get as a community release from collab.net. The problem is that the latest version only supports 10.6 and no version yet exists for 10.7.

I solved my need to interface with a subversion repository through eclipse by switching from the subclipse plugin to the subversive plugin which does have a supported bridge. I know this doesn't exactly answer how to get subclipse working but it was an alternative that worked for me and as far as I know might be the only solution until a javahl package supporting 10.7 is available.

Answer (score 0):

Open this file :

```
sudo pico /System/Library/Core​Services/SystemVersi​on.plist
```

change version to 10.6 wherever you see 10.7
install subversion
change back to 10.7

Ilias

Comment: Hi Ilias, do I need to re-install the SUBVERSION on my mac to have the javaHL installed on my LION?

Comment: You can avoid hacking your CoreServices SystemVersion.plist (scary!) by just installing the WanDisco 1.7 SVN package for OS X 10.7