# svn for eclipse on mac os lion

Tags: eclipse, macos, svn, subclipse, subversive

I need to use Subversion with Eclipse on Mac Lion. I encounter problem as below

I saw: [Subclipse in Mac OS Lion shows "Unable to load default SVN client" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791989/subclipse-in-mac-os-lion)

In my context:

- I use Mac OS Lion 10.7.2
- Eclipse version: 3.7.1 64 bit
- I install Subversion: **Universal Subversion 1.6.17 Binaries for Lion (Mac OS X 10.7)** in the page: http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/community/
- I install Subclipse by the "Install New Software..." feature of Eclipse with the update link: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x
  It install Subclipse 1.8.2, JavaHL 1.7.1.1 and some other packages.
- When I go to menu Preferences/ Team / SVN , it produce error: "Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.7.x or later required."
- I find to install SVN Kit, so use it instead of JavaHL as the very first link refer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791989/subclipse-in-mac-os-lion)), but I don't see it in Subclipse package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that you need the right native Subversion libraries for the version of Subclipse you use.  This page has information and a chart of the versions:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

The binaries on CollabNet website are still for SVN 1.6 so you either need to get SVN 1.7 binaries (MacPorts and Homebrew are good places to get it) or you need to use Subclipse 1.6.x.

Answer (score 10):

Follow the steps as below to get it working:

1. Install subclipse via update url: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x
2. Install subversion using the binary from here: http://www.ubersvn.com/download (scroll down to "Command-Line Client 1.6.18 and 1.7.6 certified by WANdisco" section since that's all you need)

Comment: I only needed step 1. I tried installing JavaHL, but that was without succes.

Comment: the Wandisco package requires you to register and it installs a bunch of other stuff.  You're much better off installing svn via Macports or Homebrew as detailed below

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution (download from WanDisco instead of CollabNet) in this thread: [Subclipse in Mac OS Lion shows "Unable to load default SVN client" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791989/subclipse-in-mac-os-lion/8072973#8072973)

Answer (score 1):

I went to this topic because I was in need to make SVN 1.7 to work with subclipse.

For those with the same problem, the easiest way to fix it is to install Subversion and JavaHL from MacPorts.

The packages you need to install with macports are subversion and subversion-javahlbindings ([check here](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=subversion)), they are both 1.7.1.

With these packages you can install the subclipse using the update site with version 1.8.x. (http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x)

If you don't have macports installed follow [these instructions](http://www.macports.org/install.php). I am sure it will be useful for other things too. You also need to install XCode from AppStore.

Comment: I updated everything using MacPorts, and my versions read correctly, but Eclipse wouldn't recognize the update. As such I tried the WandDisco solution and it worked fine. So if you have trouble with this solution, try that!

Answer (score 1):

Installing the binaries from http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone using homebrew wants SVN version 1.6 support (as I did due to interacting with some old servers), here is how I got it to work:

Install SVN 1.6 via homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew info homebrew/versions/subversion16
brew install homebrew/versions/subversion16 --java
```

Ensure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` before `/usr/bin`, so that homebrew's SVN is ran instead of OS X's.

If using Eclipse:

Be sure to install Subclipse 1.6 (e.g. use the 1.6 update site) instead of the newest one.

If you follow the homebrew formula instructions to link the java library to OS X's Extensions, you do NOT have to edit your Eclipse.ini file to include the path there.  For posterity, those commands are:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/Extensions
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This post resolved my problem: http://bridgetconsulting.com/?p=64 Requires MacPorts

Add to /opt/local/etc/macports.conf this line

```
universal_archs         i386 x86_64
```

and run

```
sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings +no_bdb +universal
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed subversion 1.7 and the java-hl bindings using homebrew by following the instructions [here](http://widerin.org/blog/using-svn-1.7-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x-lion).

Specifically:

```
[sudo] brew install subversion --universal --java
```

Then linking the installed libraries in /Library/Java/Extensions so eclipse picked them up.

```
/Library/Java/Extensions $ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib
/Library/Java/Extensions $ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.jnilib
```

Answer (score -1):

You only installed the Java HL package. Uninstall JavaHL and install the SVN Kit. You can find  options for connecting in Preferences -> Team...

Comment: You can find the SVN Kit in eclipse here on the  "Help" menu > "Install New Software"