# SVN won't run on brand new Mac OSX install

Tags: macos, svn, postgresql, dylib

I have a brand new install of Mac OS 10.7.2.  I have installed SVN on it, however, when I try to invoke Subversion, I get the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/subversion/bin/svn
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I have tried searching for the error, and it looks like that library is used primarily by PostreSQL (which I also have installed), but that is running fine.  I am a little confused as to why SVN would be trying to call this library, and furthermore why it fails.

Various user groups online state that the solution is to create a symbolic link to the 'real' PostgreSQL install, but I have done that. (See also: [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5bf26515097c3231c1b04dfdb22c036bc511926b))  I have reinstalled SVN and PostgreSQL twice now with no errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that although my PostgreSQL is using version 5.2, SVN depends on 5.3.  So if anyone runs into this problem, note that you CANNOT simply create a symbolic link to your PostgreSQL dylib, it has to be the 5.3 that comes with the install.

ie

```
ln -s libpq.5.3.dylib libpq.5.dylib
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a broken linkage:

```
/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib -> /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

I fixed this with:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
$ sudo ln -s /usr/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib
```

As suggested earlier.

After this I noticed, that subversion client is too old.
This instruction http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL suggests to download latest binaries from CollabNet, but those community built Mac packages are for older version and therefore incompatible.

> "Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.7.x or later required."

More information here: [svn for eclipse on mac os lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102759/svn-for-eclipse-on-mac-os-lion)