# Subversive error: "<file>... non-existent in that revision"

Tags: svn, subclipse, subversive

I have started to set up a new SVN repo on AWS, and am having trouble working with it from **Eclipse 3.6 Subversive 2.2.2**.

**Update:** The new repo is using the Bitnami stack with Subversion 1.7.

I have no problems with my **Eclipse 3.5 Subclipse 1.6.2** install.

In **Eclipse 3.6 Subversive 2.2.2**, if I try to open any subfolders, Subversive gives me the error:

> Get repository folder children operation failed.
>
> svn: URL 'svn://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/M1' non-existent in
> that revision

Any attempt to read the files gives me a similar error (*xxx non-existent in that revision*).

It seems like the meta-data about each commit is available, but the actual files themselves cannot be found/read.

---

**Updates:**

- I can view the history of all commits with Subversive, but can't view the actual files.
- The repo works perfectly with other SVN clients, like Subclipse, X-Code's client, SVNX.
- the issue lies with the lack of SVN 1.7 support for Subversive at the moment (Feb 2012)

---

**Answer (explained):**

ScubaZA pointed me in the right direction - the new repo was using Subversion 1.7, which is not supported by Subversive (as of Feb 2012). Subversive uses the SVNKit connectors. The other SVN clients already had support for 1.7.

Info in these related questions helped:

- [Subclipse in Mac OS Lion shows "Unable to load default SVN client" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791989/subclipse-in-mac-os-lion-shows-unable-to-load-default-svn-client-error)
- [SVN / Subversion 1.7 and Eclipse Subversive & JavaHL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840221/svn-subversion-1-7-and-eclipse-subversive-javahl)

Comment: This does not seem related to auth.  Clearly it is getting past the authentication.  I have never run SVN in AWS before.  Is it possible it is somehow reaching a different server?  What version of Subclipse did you install?  Subclipse 1.8 includes SVN 1.7.  Maybe this is some difference with 1.7 clients and the server?

Comment: Thx Mark - you are right - I updated the question. And (I can't believe this but...) I put the wrong SVN client names in the question, so I've fixed that, including adding the version numbers (not 1.8 though on Subclipse). I broke my own rule of never to post to stackoverflow in a rush.

Comment: I maintain Subclipse, so I can only guess.  I would take a look at the SVN connector you are using in Subversive as I believe they support multiple.  Maybe you are using one that cannot connect to this server for some reason such as the old JavaSVN connector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps check that your eclipse SVN connector is compatible with the SVN version installed on your server.

To check Using eclipse:

Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> SVN Connector tab

It should say something like 'SVNKit 1.x.x (SVN 1.x.x compatible)'

As far as I know the Subversive plugin does not support SVN 1.7 as yet.

Comment: thx - new Repo was using SVN 1.7. The SVNKit connectors for Subversive do not yet (Feb 2012) support SVN 1.7.