# SVN - Eclipse - OSX 10.8

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I've installed subeclipse on OSX 10.8 and get the error:

```
Incompatible JavaHL library loaded. 1.6.x or later required
```

When trying to import from SVN.

I've read this thread:
[Subclipse in Mac OS Lion shows "Unable to load default SVN client" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791989/subclipse-in-mac-os-lion-shows-unable-to-load-default-svn-client-error)

and tried a number of things suggested. Installing subeclipse 1.6 - doesnt work. Also I have tried installing Wandisco (http://www.wandisco.com/get/?f=subversion-binaries/1.7/Subversion-1.7.2_10.7.x.pkg) which the install doesnt work on 10.8 and hangs on select destination.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102759/svn-for-eclipse-on-mac-os-lion

Comment: That thread relates to Lion and not Mountain Lion

Comment: I also tried everything in that thread and it still doesnt work.